# How to create a uniform path on a wavy mesh using a bezier curve and knife projection

Tags: mesh

I want to create a path along a hilly landscape mesh. The problem is that its supposed to have a uniform width relative to the mesh.

The path has to be a very particular shape. I started by mapping the route of the path in topview using a bezier curve. Then I tried giving it thickness and using knife project to cut out the shape that I got and thats where I ran into a problem. Obviously projecting a uniform flat path onto a wavy mesh will result in a path that (on the mesh) is not uniform in width.
Now Im a bit out of ideas. I tried knife projecting the original bezier curve right away onto the mesh. this then gave me at least an accurate cut in my mesh where the center of the path is supposed to go.
but I don't really know what to do with this now.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

one way of doing this is using geometry nodes and a raycast node. You can raycast from the beziercurve down to your landscape like this:

[image]

[image]